# Android gallery: stretching and overlapping thumbnails

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-gallery

I'm doing an Android gallery and I need to have the `ImageView` which shows a picture in full screen, and on top of it -meaning that it has to overlap the ImageView- the `Gallery`.

The problem is that now the `ImageView` occupies the portion that is not occupied by the `Gallery`, but I don't know how to achieve this.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/GalleryImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/GalleryThumbnails"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/GalleryImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use layout_alignTop=[Reference] to achieve that effekt.

> Makes the top edge of this view match the top edge   of the given
>   anchor view ID.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/GalleryImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/GalleryThumbnails"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/GalleryImage" />
```

Proof that it works

[image]

Comment: in the Gallery to match the ImageView, or in the ImageView to match the root RelativeLayout?

Comment: The example should place the gallery on top of the ImageView.

Comment: what I wanna do is to put the ImageView OVER the Gallery, meaning that when the Gallery is there, it will be on top of the ImageView, and there'll be a portion (the bottom portion) of the ImageView that won't be visible,but after 5 seconds, the ImageView will be visible as the Gallery will disappear.

Comment: yes this is what the code does. It will make the Gallery overlap the ImageView. The top edge of the Gallery is aligned with the top edge if the imageview. Use android:layout_alignBottom to have the Gallery overlap the bottom part of the ImageView.

Comment: it simply doesn't work, as the ImageView completely overlaps the thumbnails gallery..

Comment: Since the Gallery comes below the ImageView in my xml the Gallery should definitely overlap the ImageView and not the other way around.

Comment: added screenshot to show that it should work. There must be something else in your code..

Comment: @Renard's code looks pretty solid, I have to agree with him. Must be something else you're doing.

Comment: maybe it could be cus the gallery viewer can only be in landscape mode?

Comment: i don't think so. My Screenshot is in portrait mode :-)